# How do I make a custom close button for google maps api v3 street view?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm trying to customize that terribly small close button in google maps api street view mode:

[image: Street view close button]

How do I customize the street view close button?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Reference

I found [this reference](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/2HsY3joJa40/FrcKKvy8nNAJ) in google groups explaining how to push a dom object into a street map view.

## Custom Javascript Code

I then did some custom coding and this is what I came up with:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function( e ){

    // Get close button and insert it into streetView
    // #button can be anyt dom element
    var closeButton = document.querySelector('#button'),
        controlPosition = google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP;

    // Assumes map has been initiated 
    var streetView = map.getStreetView();

    // Hide useless and tiny default close button
    streetView.setOptions({ enableCloseButton: false });

    // Add to street view
    streetView.controls[ controlPosition ].push( closeButton );

    // Listen for click event on custom button
    // Can also be $(document).on('click') if using jQuery
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeButton, 'click', function(){
        streetView.setVisible(false);
    });

});
```

## HTML

```html
<button id="button" class="btn">&times;</button>
```

## CSS

```css
.btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}
```

## Demo

Heres the [full demo](http://jsbin.com/eferit/3) on jsbin (**hint**: drop the street view guy onto the map).

Comment: Excellent thanks! Also note you don't need to push it into the streetview pano layer, that's just if you want to take advantage of the gmap positioning.   The listener will find the element anywhere in the page.